# T-SQL select distinct formatted datetime while still sorting as unformatted datetime

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, format, distinct

I have only SELECT permissions on the server I'm working on. I'm trying to write a query where one of the columns is a formatted datetime:

```
--mydb.EventDate is column EventDate(datetime, not null)

SELECT DISTINCT
    FORMAT(mydb.EventDate, 'M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt') as 'EventDate',
    [Other Specified Columns]
FROM
    mytsqldb.myschema.mytable AS mydb
ORDER BY 
    EventDate, [Other Specific Columns]
```

I also need to sort by that event date, chronologically. However, with that format, it gets sorted alphabetically (I think). Because of the SELECT DISTINCT, I can't convert EventDate when I ORDER BY. However, I do not want any additional columns added to the output of the query. The formatting of the datetime is mildly important, but I can give up that ghost if needed. Is what I'm looking for possible?

Comment: `"where one of the columns is a formatted datetime"`There isn't a formatted datetime in SQL Server, unless you're storing a formatted string. Which is bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `DISTINCT` use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT 
  FORMAT(mydb.EventDate, 'M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt') as 'EventDate',
  [Other Specified Columns]
FROM mytsqldb.myschema.mytable as mydb
GROUP BY mydb.EventDate, FORMAT(mydb.EventDate, 'M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt'), [Other Specified Columns]
ORDER BY mydb.EventDate, [Other Specific Columns]
```

or with a subquery:

```
SELECT FORMAT(t.EventDate, 'M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt') AS EventDate, [Other Specified Columns]
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    mydb.EventDate,
    [Other Specified Columns]
  FROM mytsqldb.myschema.mytable as mydb 
) AS t
ORDER BY t.evDate, [Other Specific Columns]
```

Comment: The select statement I use is about 3000 characters long, and I'd have to make any changes to both the GROUP BY and SELECT statements. Is there any good way to avoid that in a query, or should I just toughen up and deal with it in order to keep my formatting?

Comment: If you mean that there are many columns that you need in the SELECT list then yes you must repeat them again in the GROUP BY clause plus the column EventDate, so this extends even further the sql statement. There is no other way to get distinct rows and also use EventDate in the ORDER BY clause (or at least none that I know of).

Comment: @BlairCliff try another option with a subquery in my edited answer (although I can't tell about its efficiency).